# XNA C# File I/O using a .txt

Tags: c#, file, input, xna, output

sorry in advance if this seems trivial. Read a few tutorials/notes and still cannot get my head around this...

I am currently making a puzzle game in which the player controls a character. Each time the character moves "1 map tile" in any 4 way direction (N,S,E,W) an int will +1. The number of this integer is currently displayed on the game screen along with some small text, informing the player of their current "moves".

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(debugfont, "Moves Taken: " + MoveCounter, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
```

What I want to do is take the information that's being stored/displayed above and place it into an external file (.txt) which can then be viewed at a later stage when the user chooses the "HighScores" option from the Main Menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[File.AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendtext.aspx) and [TextWriter.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2t77weh.aspx) is possible approach:

```
using(var output = new File.AppendText("highscore.txt"))
{
    output.Write("Moves Taken: {0}", MoveCounter);
}
```

Comment: I see, would this be placed into the "Update" method of my "HighScore" gamestate? Also if the user were to click the "HighScores" option on the menu state, how would I take the information on the txt and allow them to view it? Thanks :)

Comment: @CraigThomson `File` class have plenty of helper methods to read/write data (easier to use that directly creating `FileStream`/readers) - read and try.

Comment: Ok reading through the tutorials. I will read and give it a try, will post back here once I am done, cheers.